# Opening URL from SMS

Tags: android, url, text, sms

I have an app that listens for incoming messages. When I get a specific message, I extract the text and save it to a file. The message consists of text and an URL. How can I open this url from the text file?

Comment: I believe you would somehow have to communicate with a browser to do this. I'm unaware of how this might be accomplished, but you should probably see if you can somehow pass an URL to the default browser.

Answer (score 0):

Use intent with Action.VIEW and pass url with this intent.

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
startActivity(browserIntent);
```

This will open a browser (I believe the user selects which one) and goes to the url